# computing a map with nested maps to have a specific value being transformed

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

I have a specific map like this:

```
"specialContent" : null, // needs to be transformed
"hasFlag": true,
"tehNumbers": 42432,
"ipsumStruct": {
  "loremKey": "loremValue",
  "subStructKey": {
    "subStructSubKey": "Apemaster 3000",
      "specialContentTwo": null // needs to be tranformed
  }
},
"foo": "fooValue",
"bar": "barValue"
```

As you can see there a specific entries with the key **specialContent** and **specialContentTwo**. The values of these entries have to be transformed. The logic to transform them is not the important part here.

I managed to iterate over the first level of the map and successfully transformed the first **specialContent** entry. I used `map.compute` for this.

My issue here is that the code for actually trying to transform the nested occurances of **specialContentTwo** but I do not find an elegant or smart way to do so. I bruteforce iterativaly through the map.

I look for something that fulfills the following:

- Use a predicate for the value like `content -> content instanceof Content`
- transform/compute the new value for those found by the predicate
- find occurances also in nested maps

Is there a MapUtils method or something that may fit my needs here exactly?

Comment: I want to clarify, "specialContent", "foo", "bar" are keys in your map?

Comment: Yes I tried to represent the map in json so it is clear what is *key* and what is *value*